# Change the default user and group from root to something attribute-driven in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm using chef-solo with vagrant

Chef defaults to root for everything. I want to only use root for a couple of things but use a functional user for everything else.

I'm basically installing a few of packages to standard locations (should be done as root).
And, then I'm compiling a bunch of stuff to a non-standard location. I want this entire tree to be owned by non-root user/group. Can I set the default user/group to an attribute?

More broadly, why does chef want to act as root and why is changing the default user to non-root not a more common request?

Specifically, the `bash` resource can take a user but this is not a full login of the user. So, the home dir is still root's home dir (which the user can not write to), the group of files created is still root. So,

```
bash "foo" do
  user node[:globals][:username]
  code <<-EOH
    # do stuff
  EOH
end
```

`do stuff` is not a full login as user.

This question is related to https://serverfault.com/questions/402881/execute-as-vagrant-user-not-root-with-chef-solo and the bug mentioned there that is a won't fix: http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1523 I guess I need to look closer, maybe at the environment attribute to execute: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most chef resources take a user (or owner) and group attributes to change the default. You can create the directory, setting the owner, group and mode to anything, you can execute (compile?) as a non-root user.

Check the resources your using for these attributes. It's possible to store usernames in attributes or environments and then use those values in your recipe resource blocks as the user to run commands or create resources as.

A good reference for default resources: https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html

ie

```
directory '/tmp/what?' do
  owner node[:username]
  group node[:group]
  mode 00755
end
```

or

```
execute 'gcc somefile.cc' do
  user node[:user]
  group node[:group]
end
```

If there's a specific action you can't figure out, point it out.

Comment: so what about `bash` resource?

Comment: Not sure what bash resource you're using, but you can run bash scripts using script[1], and specify the user to the script as, as above.

[1] http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Script

Comment: As per my link, the bash provide takes a `user` attribute

Comment: oh, so it is a full login as user? //snark

Comment: whats with the crazy 00755? shouldn't that be just 0755

Comment: This ensures ruby interprets it as octal mode. If you only use four digits and the first is non-zero, ruby will read the number as a decimal. The leading 0 indicates octal. You can also use 0o0755, but confusingly this isn't necessary for octals. (it is for hex, 0xNNN and binary 0bNNN). Just one of those ruby quirks. Alternatively, you can use a string, ala "0755" or even "755"